# use across() to mutate on selected col in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compute percent change over each year for each col of the data frame. I am using `mutate(across())` to achieve that but I couldn't get the desired result. I want to add a col `annual_rate` for each of the column after `year`.

```
> test %>%  group_by(cnt, year) %>% 
+     mutate(across(.cols= c(4:14), .fns = ~ (.x - lag(.x))/lag(.x))) 
# A tibble: 6 x 17
# Groups:   cnt, year [6]
   c_id cnt    year   agr   min   man    pu   con   wrt   tra   com   fin   dwe   pub
  <dbl> <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 ARG    1990  35.3 1036.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     1 ARG    1991  36.6 1049.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     1 ARG    1992  37.2 1076.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4     1 ARG    1993  38.5 1330.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5     1 ARG    1994  41.6 1245.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6     1 ARG    1995  45.7 1541.    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# ... with 3 more variables: oth <dbl>, tot <dbl>, region <chr>
```

```
structure(list(c_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cnt = c("ARG", "ARG", 
"ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG"), year = 1990:1995, agr = c(35.2973158777038, 
36.58634760919, 37.2437345753805, 38.4767490050774, 41.6436856831634, 
45.6644505817192), min = c(1036.08672560808, 1049.42139380361, 
1076.41365675798, 1330.14649855565, 1245.03071667624, 1541.26132938926
), man = c(98.3804629426408, 107.250659295854, 117.672382134779, 
129.106927777147, 139.306771251582, 147.641854882585), pu = c(36.256985900479, 
37.8510943815731, 41.7758992836601, 44.941028464646, 46.673171825651, 
57.0773725261619), con = c(34.7150547044804, 45.7547521931977, 
54.1067841716466, 72.2898270170184, 80.2420203536462, 59.6224533625281
), wrt = c(43.241355357916, 47.9917267896102, 51.5482935558095, 
51.185824409496, 57.7225056379752, 58.1435531505049), tra = c(35.1363373438996, 
37.2876787520265, 38.9332568433761, 37.7163386221175, 37.2453889533926, 
40.3075666246957), com = c(61.2045510047221, 66.6570912685059, 
71.3233166548407, 68.9806068883313, 70.7132400620238, 70.0561222484919
), fin = c(185.731956159728, 202.278284887732, 216.438468826725, 
209.32926782928, 214.587046934706, 212.59293622833), dwe = c(311.258962769405, 
338.98812903314, 362.718700298966, 350.804437618659, 359.61586949591, 
356.274151090864), pub = c(42.0127530183895, 41.0069267011244, 
42.4673143780743, 45.2664042716438, 44.8156573199841, 46.9417750020651
), oth = c(19.6015737261148, 19.1322855184293, 19.8136628480103, 
21.1195988898731, 22.0019653249359, 22.5383358086985), tot = c(53.3047313441692, 
56.8249180947696, 61.0812876392371, 64.6790602781848, 68.6928147960135, 
69.9193068891647), region = c("Latin America", "Latin America", 
"Latin America", "Latin America", "Latin America", "Latin America"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `group_by` `year` and `cnt` you'll have only one row for each group, `lag` of which will return `NA`. I think you need to group only by country (`cnt`).

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  arrange(cnt, year) %>%
  group_by(cnt) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols= agr:tot, .fns = ~ (.x - lag(.x))/lag(.x))) %>%
  ungroup

#   c_id cnt    year     agr     min     man      pu    con      wrt     tra
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1 ARG    1990 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA       NA     
#2     1 ARG    1991  0.0365  0.0129  0.0902  0.0440  0.318  0.110    0.0612
#3     1 ARG    1992  0.0180  0.0257  0.0972  0.104   0.183  0.0741   0.0441
#4     1 ARG    1993  0.0331  0.236   0.0972  0.0758  0.336 -0.00703 -0.0313
#5     1 ARG    1994  0.0823 -0.0640  0.0790  0.0385  0.110  0.128   -0.0125
#6     1 ARG    1995  0.0966  0.238   0.0598  0.223  -0.257  0.00729  0.0822
# … with 7 more variables: com <dbl>, fin <dbl>, dwe <dbl>, pub <dbl>,
#   oth <dbl>, tot <dbl>, region <chr>
```

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'cnt', we can use `diff` to get the difference between adjacent elements `across` the columns of interest and divide by the `lag` of that column

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
    arrange(cnt, year) %>%
    group_by(cnt) %>%
    mutate(across(agr:tot, ~ c(NA, diff(.x)/lag(.x))))
```